# Bookmarks mode with quick selection list and autodetected names from context?

Tags: bookmarks

I like `recentf` and like `jump-to-register`, `ibuffer`, `ido-switch-buffer` but during code investigation I need a lot of switching between already visited points.

Having short memory I like reviewing possibilities through list of available options, like that provide `recentf`. But that all lack support for positioning across files.

Seems that this known as bookmarking and I read `(elisp)Bookmarks` and try most promising http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus

That bookmarking packages provide persistent storage and simple interface to select the bookmarks but I don't like type bookmark name.

Usually name can be easy derived from context - in RST mode - this is section title, in C/ELisp - function name, in Info - page title... For C++/Java I like to see also enclosing context - namespece and package path (through CEDET or other sources).

Are there any implementation or support from another packages (or extension point) to get automatically named bookmarks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) already provides [*automatically named bookmarks*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks).

   By default, the names used do not come from RST mode section titles etc., however.

   `C-x p RET` creates a bookmark at point without prompting you for the name. By default, it is named using the *current buffer name* preceded by the *position* in the buffer. For example, the autonamed bookmark in buffer `foo.el` at position 58356 is called `000058356 foo.el` by default.

   (You can customize the format of autonamed bookmarks using options `bmkp-autoname-bookmark-function` and `bmkp-autoname-format`.)
2. You can also define your own bookmark types, and a jump command that is specific to only bookmarks of that type.  There are many **Bookmark+** jump commands that are specific to **Bookmark+** bookmark types.  You can control the naming and any other bookmark attributes when you define a bookmark type.
3. You can also easily rename bookmarks.  So you could use autonamed bookmarks with the default names or other names to start with, and then systematically rename them according to your own design. (If your design can fit with customization of options `bmkp-autoname-bookmark-function` and `bmkp-autoname-format` then you would not need to rename, of course.)
4. You can define a particular set of bookmarks to use as the completion candidates for choosing a bookmark name when jumping to a bookmark.  That is, you can define a bookmark jump command whose candidates are from a limited set, not all bookmarks.  Completion is very quick. It is not related to automatic naming, but can mean more time saved.

Answer (score 0):

`semantic-mru-bookmark-mode` is interesting thing but UI is very limiting in compare to `bookmark+`. It has `C-x B` key binding only in buffers that have `semantic` enabled and completion through minibufer. For Java code its name is package+class without method name ((